# How to inspect File descriptors leaks in a heap dump hprof file

Tags: java, file-descriptor, heap-dump, hprof

I have an instance of an app server's heap dump (hprof). How do I use visualvm or any other tool to inspect leaking File descriptors?

I did check the file descriptors in use by running

```
sudo lsof | grep java | wc -l
```

When I run the following OOQL I get a list of FileDescriptors

```
select x from java.io.FileDescriptor x
```

But how do I approach finding the abusing classes using the heap dump analysis?